# Having to explicitly render :layout => 'application' in controller actions in my Rails 3 app

Tags: layout, ruby-on-rails-3, render

I am having to explicitly render :layout => 'application' in my controller actions in order to get my new rails 3 app to actually use the application.html.erb layout file.

Any obvious things to look for that I am doing wrong?  If I don't call the :layout option it just doesn't render the layout.  I get a message like:

Processing by FooController#index as HTML

...when I read the terminal window trace on WEBrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with an app upgraded from Rails 2.3.8 to 3.0.3. In my case, all controllers except one rendered properly with the app/views/layouts/application.html.haml. When I finally added `render :layout => 'application'`, the non-conforming controller rendered properly.

Comment: having to add `render :layout => 'application'` to get your application layout to work means you are doing something extremely wrong.  Please, never do this.  See danhere's answer for the most likely solution to your issue.

Comment: This is not the solution, but a symptom

Answer (score 14):

I know this is resing a dead thread but I recently ran into the same issue. My controller was inheriting from ActionController::Base and not ApplicationController. I had the same issue as you were having, until I fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, nice tip to check out.

Comment: +1 from me too.  I was porting a Rails2.3 app to Rails3 and was confounded by why it wasn't rendering the default layout.  @danhere's answer probably deserves the checkmark.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue, the problem ended up being that someone had defined an initialize method for the controller.

Comment: Yes, and that solves my problem . I think we both forgot to add `super` at the end of the controller constructor.

Comment: both this answer and the inheritance answer point to the problem - that ApplicationController.initialize is not called