# Application layout not shown in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked over my basic starting code to be sure I didn't make a spelling goof. You may see something I did. I cannot get my application.html.erb to appear. My basic app has only one model. I haven't installed a controller and view working the model first via TDD. I installed  'twitter-bootstrap-rails' and followed the install procedure. I did not test the view before installing bootstrap. My ruby is 1.9.3 and my rails app is 3.2.11 Here is my routes.rb

```
 root :to => 'weather#index'
 resources :weather
```

Here is my applicable Gemfile

```
 group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2'
   #gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.0' bailed when it seemed to conflict
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 end
```

Here is my controller:

```
 class WeatherController < ActionController::Base
   def index
   end
 end
```

Here is my views/weather/index.html.erb:

```
 test
```

My views/layouts/application.html.erb has the twitter-bootstrap-rails layout with a <%= yield %>

I'm aware that my controller is not named the Rails way. When I changed it to weathers in all the appropriate places, the result is the same. I get the word test with NONE of the application html code. The source of the result is just "test" with no html headers or output. If I put layout: 'application' in the index action I get it to appear but not the contents of the index.html.erb. I have looked in SO but they do not seem to apply, or work. Being new at this is an impediment. I'm sure I overlooked something stupid. Thanks for looking, sam

Comment: have you tested it with a bare bones application.html.erb file? e.g. just the HTML skeleton without the bootstrap stuff in it?  Maybe setting an @test = test variable in the index action and calling it from your test index.html.erb layout?

Comment: Yes. In my application.html.erb file I yanked everything in the <head> tag and get the same result. The variable passed fine so it knows it's a Rails erb file. Thx.

Comment: Have you tried the solution below in the answer?  Inherit from ApplicationController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller should be inheriting from ApplicationController not from ActionController::Base

Just referring to my own question on exactly the same problem some time back: [Having to explicitly render :layout => 'application' in controller actions in my Rails 3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994327/having-to-explicitly-render-layout-application-in-controller-actions-in-my)

Changing that worked for several people.

Comment: It's very close. This time and earlier I got different errors. The most recent is Sass::SyntaxError on the line for <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application". But my "test" passes through this time so this fixed this issue. Can't fault the answer if it exposes another problem. THX.